# tina convergence issue

Tags: circuit-analysis, spice, texas-instruments

I have created a circuit using TINA and it has given me a "convergence error". TINA is telling me the issue is LED1 however I am unable to troubleshoot the problem.

The circuit is as below:
[image]

Comment: I don't use TINA, but just about every simulator wants you to designate one node as ground.

Comment: Not that I can make any sense of what this 'circuit' is supposed to do as it looks like a random set of components linked together to form ???. However LED1 connects to the base of T1 but there is no current limiting resistor so If T3 is on it will short out anything over about 2.5V on the collector. Try adding a 1k0 resistor in series with LED 1 and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

A convergence error means you have positive feedback in your system and it 'goes to infinity' or your system is as such that it is hard to find the steady state conditions.

It looks like you need a ground.

Another way to combat convergence problems in simulations (not just tina) is to:
1) Introduce parasitic series resistance (kind of like a wire under 1 ohm usually)
2) Introduce parasitic parallel resistance (1e9 Ohms will help some nodes converge, and will have little effect on most circuits)
3) Parasitic capacitance to ground (1e-14 F will knock out some high frequency  numerical errors that may cause the simulation to 'blow up')